# What is the difference between calling event handler and PerformClick();?

Tags: c#, delegates

What is the difference between two following code fragments?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button2_Click(sender, e);
}
```

And this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button2.PerformClick();
}
```

Both seem to work. What happens in the background?

Comment: What if the same event handler is assigned to two buttons and the code uses the `sender` object to determine what to do? What if there are multiple event handlers associated with a button click event? What if the event handler assigned to the button changes over time?

Comment: perform clicks fires all other events like previewmousedown etc while button2_click just calles the function that is triggerd by the actual click of the button

Comment: @DavidG Makes sense. Is there even a difference in a use case where it is only assigned once and it is used by only one method?

Comment: @DenisSchaf I see. So the PerformClick is kinda a wrapper around the event handler

Comment: PerformClick simulates a use has clicked the buttons with all its consequences while the other option only fires this exact eventhandler